# How to use htaccess to redirect to a parallel subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm a htaccess noob.. so here's my question

I'm try to redirect from

http://www.website.com/books/726/m/32.html to

http://www.website.com/books/726/d/32.html

726 and 32 are dynamic numbers

I just can't get it to work..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why isn't it working?

Comment: what are the errors you are facing ?

Answer (score 1):

Try below rule, I am assuming you are using this .htaccess in root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^books/([\d]+)/m/([\d]+)\.html books/$1/d/$2\.html [L]
```